# Python Pandas csv import "Error tokenizing data" - show error line content

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm reading a large csv file

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';',
                 encoding='cp850', quoting=3)
```

On some lines I get the error message because of extra semicolons

```
Error tokenizing data. C error: 
Expected 33 fields in line 23836, saw 34
```

When opening the file in Vim, most of the time the error is exactly at this line. But sometimes is not at this line number, but a line/a few lines above.

If I search for the line manually, I get a different line number, which is the line number where I find the error in the editor.

```
with open(filename, encoding='cp850') as f1:
    lines = f1.readlines()
    [(e, l) for e, l in enumerate(lines) 
        if len(split(';')) == 34]
```

Result

```
[(23835, '.....
```

So for this example, the error was not in line 23836, but 23835.

This problems occurs with both the c and the python engine of read_csv.

It would be very helpful if read_csv could show the error line content with the error message.

Is there a way to do this?

## UPDATE:

It seems that there are line breaks within lines of the import file and that read_csv seems to accept those lines as correct if a line is split into two lines, so that after 33 fields there always is a break. But from that line on, the line count in the error message no longer matching the line breaks of the file.

Comment: This error will be common where your header length is less than the number of values in some row. Mostly it cause by inappropriate seperator

Comment: Doesn't it tell you the line with unexpected field number? `Expected 33 fields in line 23836, saw 34` That's what you posted.

Comment: @SpghttCd the error is a line above in this case. My example code explains that. Also, this is not caused by the header, but by the file having a combination of extra semicolons and a few line feeds that don't belong, which I need to clean up. This is hard, because I can't trust the line number from the error message.

Comment: Would you be happy with ignoring the error on read and then filter out the row with the error after you have the `DataFrame`?

Comment: No, I would like to see the error and make the import stop but see the line with the error so I can fix it and restart the import.

Comment: @576i You misunderstand your example code. The line with the bad number of separators is the 23836th line of your csv file. But if you count it with `enumerate` you'll end up with an index of 23835, because python is 0-indexed. But still it is the 23836th line of the file...

Comment: Line breaks _within_ lines...? Now at least me would need some example lines which show what this should mean. `readlines` gives the same result like `read_csv` , so I can hardly imagine line breaks _within lines_...

Comment: @SpghttCd Thanks for trying to help. I'm curious about this behaviour, too. 

I'll try to generate a similar example file in my spare time and will, if I manage to recreate that, open an issue with pandas.

Answer (score 0):

The line with the error is the 23836th line of the csv file, which will have the index 23835 when enumerated in Python, as Python is zero-indexed.

However, what is the exact cause of the error?
If it's just about lines, which have one or more semicolons too much *at the end*, then you could throw them away easily by explicitly read the first 33 columns:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', usecols=range(33), encoding='cp850', quoting=3)
```

Comment: This does not help, as the semicolons are in a field in the middle of the line. And in other cases the line number has been off by more - if the fields contained unwanted line breaks. So this question is really about: how do you see the line that causes the error with the least amount of trouble.

Comment: Hmm, that's bad. Could you post the error line and a good one as an example, so that people can examine the issue by themselves? And I saw that you deactivate quoting on purpose, so I assume that this is not an option...?

Comment: Ok, the question `"how do you see the line that causes the error with the least amount of trouble"` is not too hard to answer: `"For example by reading the line number information in the error message of pd.read_csv()"`

Comment: These are external files with data that can't be shared.  I have to import them, locate errors, fix them until they import. I can write code like in my second example, but I think there may be a way to tell pandas read_csv to show the line it thinks that is wrong...

Comment: No need to post secret or personal data - try to post the _structure_ which differs between a good and a bad line with dummy data - and of course not 33 columns but two or three, just for an example... And again: did you understand that pandas _already provides the line number you are interested in_?

Answer (score 0):

*Create a sample file with anonymized data from the bad line 23835 ± 2 lines beneath:*

```
import re
bad_idx = 23835
with open(filename, 'r') as f_in, open(filename[-4:] + '_dummy.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    for i, line in enumerate(f_in):
        line = re.sub('[a-zA-Z0-9]+', line)
        if (i > bad_idx-3) and (i < bad_idx+3) or i==0:
            f_out.write(line)
```

---

*Print bad lines and list of their line numbers (1-based):*

```
bad_lines = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    n_col = len(f.readline().split(';'))
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if len(line.split(';')) != n_col:
            print(i+2, line)
            bad_lines.append(i+2)
print(bad_lines)
```